# How to prevent buffer seek in one window if I select in another?

Tags: vim

On VIM, I often open 2 windows on the same file, one for reading, other for writing. But when I select some text on the writing one window, the other seeks to the text I just selected, moving away from the place I was reading, annoying the hell out of me. How can I prevent such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I believe by two windows you meant split windows opened using `vsplit` or `hsplit`. If that's the case, you can turn off this behavior by disabling `scrollbind`.

`:set scrollbind!` or `:set scb!`

Comment: It is much worse now. Scroll position of the two windows seems connected. If I scroll one window, the other follows. The other seems to be able to scroll independently from the first, but if I change the cursor back to the first window, it scrolls back to previous position.